# MongoDB match in aggregation lookup

Tags: mongodb

This is my current query:

```
db.ministryteams.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            "id_ministryTeam": { $toObjectId: "$_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "profiles",
            localField: "phone",
            foreignField: "phone",
            as: "profile"
        },
    },
    { $unwind: "$profile" },
    {
        $project: {
            "profile._id": 1,
            "profile.name": 1,
            "profile.phone": 1,
            "profile.type": 1,
            "profile.contactAllowed": 1,
            "profile.createAt": 1,
            "id_ministryTeam": 1,
            "_id": 0
        }
    }
])
```

And currently this query returns two profiles:

```
[{
  "id_ministryTeam": "ObjectId(\"62a79c461df25412ae7ef2ff\")",
  "profile": {
    "_id": "ObjectId(\"62a798074e105c2b74fe6d81\")",
    "name": "Informe seu nome aqui.",
    "contactAllowed": true,
    "type": "member",
    "phone": "16900001111"
  }
},
{
  "id_ministryTeam": "ObjectId(\"62a79cf21df25412ae7ef311\")",
  "profile": {
    "_id": "ObjectId(\"62a79cf21df25412ae7ef30e\")",
    "name": "Informe seu nome aqui.",
    "contactAllowed": true,
    "type": "member",
    "phone": "16900001112"
  }
}]
```

I would like to bring only one result, the profile._id: "62a798074e105c2b74fe6d81", I made several attempts with the match, but I couldn't get the expected result, if anyone can help me.

Comment: add a `$match` stage before `$project` stage to match `profile._id`, the second option you can avoid `$unwind` stage instead you can use $filter operator to filter specific profile id in the direct `$project` stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
db.ministryteams.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            "id_ministryTeam": { $toObjectId: "$_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "profiles",
            localField: "phone",
            foreignField: "phone",
            as: "profile"
        },
    },
    { $unwind: "$profile" },
    { $match: { "profile._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("your_ID_here") } },
    {
        $project: {
            "profile._id": 1,
            "profile.name": 1,
            "profile.phone": 1,
            "profile.type": 1,
            "profile.contactAllowed": 1,
            "profile.createAt": 1,
            "id_ministryTeam": 1,
            "_id": 0
        }
    }
])
```